# Strange behavior in Python redirection via subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, lxml, bottle

I have a really strange bug going on that I have not been able to solve.  I have minimized my code to the minimal amount to reproduce the problem:

```
from lxml import etree
xsd_prs = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
print "**", xsd_prs
```

The command I execute looks like:

```
cmd = 'python myprog.py -f myfile.xsd > out.txt 2>&1'
```

When I run this from the command line I get what I expect in `out.txt`:

```
** <lxml.etree.XMLParser object at 0x10b0fd550>
```

However, when I run this from within a Python/Bottle-based web application using the following:

```
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
pro.wait()
```

Here, `etree.XMLParser()` function doesn't return anything. I just get the following in the `out.txt` file:

```
**
```

I should also mention that I have been using this same `subprocess.Popen()` approach to execute all kinds of different commands without fail, except for this one. **Why is the string representation of the object not being output?**

I also tried the same thing using Python's built-in XML parser:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(fn)
doc = tree.getroot()
print "***", doc
```

Get similar result when running from command line:

```
*** <Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema' at 0x115675f90>
```

versus running from web application:

```
***
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was going on here, and it was not obvious at all.  When I tried to write out the `xsd_prs` object, somehow breaks all subsequent redirection.  The crazy thing is that if I tried to redirect the object, neither would any other subsequent print statement redirect, so it looked like my program was not working at all.  Once I remove the `print "**", xsd_prs`, all subsequent strings which had proper string representations could be redirected.

I first discovered this by printing `dir(xsd_prs)` which actually output a list of methods I could call on the object, which actually proved that the `XMLParser()` was returning an object.

I also found if I created another output file within my Python program, I could write the string representation of the object fine, but just not via redirection.

If anyone has any links to explain why Python redirection works this way, I would be interested if you could post in comments below or add a more detailed answer.